# CakePHP TinyAuth Adapter Implementation

Tags: cakephp, conventions, psr-4, cakephp-4.x

I'm using TinyAuth CakePHP plugin to manage permissions on my website.

They also have a plugin to manage the ACL (access control list) using a Database with CakePHP 3.7+, but the plugin isn't working with CakePHP 4.0

I'm currently writing custom adapters to manage the authorizations with the Database, like suggested [here](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth/blob/master/docs/AuthorizationAdapter.md).

My main problem is : I don't know where should I write my new adapters ?

Currently, they're in the TinyAuth vendor folder and I import them in *app_local.php* like this :

```
 'TinyAuth' => [
        'multiRole' => true,
        'aclAdapter' => TinyAuth\Auth\AclAdapter\DbAclAdapter::class,
    ],
```

And this is working.
I didn't manage to make them work in my project folder, cause I cannot import the class (???)

Is it a safe / good way to do it ? Is it better for me to create my own plugin, or to write my php class elsewhere and import it ? Is it safe to import files in CakePHP 4 *app_local.php* ?

I'm really new to PSR-4 and CakePHP framework standards, so sorry if my question is dumb, but I really want to make things correctly...

Thank you by advance

Comment: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth-backend/tree/master/docs#enable-the-adapters You cannot just invent new class names and hope things work, they will not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I indeed followed this page to add the class in TinyAuth like the code I mentioned in my question, and also implement the adapter interface and it's working. But I doubt placing the custom file I created in the TinyAuth vendor is good practice. Is it better if : the files stays in TinyAuth\Auth\AclAdapter, if I put it in my sources or if I create a plugin especially for that ? Thank you again for your work with TinyAuth and your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should never put stuff in the `vendor` folder, unless you're debugging, or you're facing some very, very weird edge case that absolutely cannot be solved in any other way, which however should be extremely rare. You'll loose your changes when the dependency is being updated.

If you want to learn about PSR-4, there's endless resources for that, start for example at the official website: **https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/**

All that being said, a quick example for a default CakePHP 4.x application based on the official application template:

- Filepath: `src/TinyAuth/Auth/AclAdapter/DbAclAdapter.php`
- Namespace: `App\TinyAuth\Auth\AclAdapter`
- Classname: `DbAclAdapter`
- Usage: `'aclAdapter' => \App\TinyAuth\Auth\AclAdapter\DbAclAdapter::class,`

Whether you use the fully qualified name when referencing your class (leading backslash required), or using `use` statements to import the name, really doesn't matter from a technical point of view, it will work either way in any PHP file.

Whether you put your custom code directly in your app, or in a plugin or a regular library, really depends on how you plan to use it. If you want to reuse it, or make it public, then you'd probably want to to put it in a plugin/library.